# What is the `version` in yarn.lock `__metadata`?

Tags: yarnpkg

At the top of my `yarn.lock` file I see:

```
__metadata:
  version: 5
  cacheKey: 8
```

I have no idea what the `version` or `cacheKey` is, and I haven't found any documentation for them on yarn's website. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply the [yarn.lock](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/) version, originally introduced [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/commit/2f9e8073d15745f9d53e6b8b42fa9c81eb143d54):

> When upgraded, the lockfile entries have to be resolved again (but the specific versions are still pinned, no worry). Bump it when you change the fields within the Package type; no more no less.

More details on the currently implemented resolution logic:

[github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/packages/yarnpkg-core/sources/Project.ts](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/packages/yarnpkg-core/sources/Project.ts)

---

Typical scenario

My lockfile version updated locally because my latest Homebrew Yarn version was running behind on `3.2.0-rc.10`, despite running `brew upgrade` and `yarn -v` still showing this older version.

However a bot (might be team member) already upgraded Yarn to `3.2.0-rc.12`, versioned / committed / locked remotely in `.yarnrc.yml` and *npm.packageManager* ([example](https://github.com/leotm/react-native-template-typescript/pull/294)).

This is what we want for consistency, so we could add a `package.json` script to use it instead

```json
// ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "setup": "yarn",
    // ...
// ...
```

If frequently switching between `classic`, `stable` and `canary` - `cd ~ && yarn set version <ver>` may bump your local Yarn version too (then remember to clear generated files).